# laravel how to save input values in session

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have problem with storing and retrive data from session, the problem if I added data to session doesn't appear in the next page, so I have to add it again which means data doesn't appear if added from the first time!!

```
 $(document).on('click', '.btn_getbids', function(e) {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }});
   e.preventDefault();
 var form = document.forms.namedItem("booking-form"); 
 var formData = new FormData(form); 
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addItem',
    contentType: false, 
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {   },
    });});
```

**controller**

```
 public function addItem(Request $request) {

$request->session()->put('country', $request->country);
$request->session()->put('administrative_area_level_1', $request->administrative_area_level_1);
$request->session()->put('locality', $request->locality);
$request->session()->put('datepicker', $request->datepicker);
$request->session()->put('pass_no', $request->pass_no);
$request->session()->put('vehicle_no', $request->vehicle_no);
$request->session()->put('day_no', $request->day_no);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To store data in the session, you will typically use the put method or the session helper:

// Via a request instance...

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

// Via the global helper...

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

Flash Data

Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next request. You may do so using the flash method. Data stored in the session using this method will only be available during the subsequent HTTP request, and then will be deleted. Flash data is primarily useful for short-lived status messages:

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

If you need to keep your flash data around for several requests, you may use the reflash method, which will keep all of the flash data for an additional request. If you only need to keep specific flash data, you may use the keep method:

```
$request->session()->reflash();

$request->session()->keep(['username', 'email']);
```

Comment: I know about flash and I don't want to use it because its the same result, the problem is the data doesnt appear in next page in the first time of adding that is the problem!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to watch your session via:
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar , then you will find the issue easily.

Comment: don't know how to use this!!

Comment: There is a documentation below. Just run the installation command and add         the `ServiceProvider` to `config/app`. But I am just repeating what you could have read yourself. After this you will be able to see all your `sessions` that are stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
Session::put([
'country' => $request->country,
'administrative_area_level_1' => $request->administrative_area_level_1,
'locality' => $request->locality,
'datepicker' => $request->datepicker,
'pass_no' => $request->pass_no,
'vehicle_no' => $request->vehicle_no,
'day_no' => $request->day_no
]);
```